# Reading data from MTLBuffer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I need to read data from a `MTLBuffer` after processing on the GPU. So far I've tried following code, but it always crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error code.

```
struct gauss_model {
  var mean : [Float32] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0];
  var covMat : [[Float32]] = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]];
  var invCovMat : [[Float32]] = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]];
  var samples : Int32 = 0;
}

self.gaussModels = [gauss_model](count: Int(10), repeatedValue: gauss_model())
self.modelsBuffer = self.device.newBufferWithBytes(self.gaussModels, length:      self.gaussModels.count * sizeof(gauss_model), options: MTLResourceOptions.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
commandEncoder.setBuffer(self.modelsBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)

    // execute GPU code

var model = unsafeBitCast(self.modelsBuffer.contents(), UnsafeMutablePointer<gauss_model>.self)
NSLog("%@", model.memory.mean) // crashes on this statement
```

I've also tried different approaches of obtaining the value like

```
var model = UnsafeMutablePointer<gauss_model>(self.modelsBuffer.contents())
// iterate over models with model.memory and model.successor()
```

or

```
var model = UnsafeMutablePointer<[gauss_model]>(self.modelBuffer.contents())
let models : [gauss_model] = model.memory
```

but none of them worked. Is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem. The problem was in my wrong assumption about memory management in Swift and the fact that the function  `newBufferWithBytes` does only a shallow copy. Calling the function only copied the pointers to `mean`, `covMat` and `invCovMat` arrays and `self.modelBuffer.contents()` contained pointers to uninitialized memory. Accessing the memory was causing the crash.

Comment: Since googling 'reading from MTLBuffer' quickly lead here, it would be great if you could include code that actually works in your answer.

Comment: Same here. I also found this: 
http://metalkit.org/2017/04/30/working-with-memory-in-metal.html

Answer (score 0):

If you come from google trying to read a simple MTLBuffer of integer, here is how i did it.

I'm not super confident in my code but it seems to works. (I also sent a bug report to Apple because the swift documentation for this is written in Objective-C)

```
let bufferSize = 10
let rawbufferSize = bufferSize * MemoryLayout<Int>.stride

let oneArray: [Int] = Array(repeating: 1, count: bufferSize)

let BufferA = device.makeBuffer(bytes: oneArray, length: rawbufferSize, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared)
let BufferB = device.makeBuffer(bytes: oneArray, length: rawbufferSize, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared)
let BufferResult = device.makeBuffer(bytes: oneArray, length: rawbufferSize, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared)

let commandBuffer = queue?.makeCommandBuffer()
let computeEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()

computeEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
computeEncoder?.setBuffer(BufferA, offset: 0, index: 0)
computeEncoder?.setBuffer(BufferB, offset: 0, index: 1)
computeEncoder?.setBuffer(BufferResult, offset: 0, index: 2)

let gridSize = MTLSizeMake(bufferSize * MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, 1, 1)

let threadGroupSize = pipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup > bufferSize ? bufferSize : pipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup

computeEncoder?.dispatchThreads(
    MTLSizeMake(rawbufferSize, 1, 1),
    threadsPerThreadgroup: MTLSizeMake(threadGroupSize, 1, 1 ))

computeEncoder?.endEncoding()
commandBuffer?.commit()
commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()

// Ewww
var rawPointer = BufferResult?.contents()
var typedPointer = rawPointer?.bindMemory(to: Int.self, capacity: rawbufferSize)
let bufferedPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: typedPointer, count: rawbufferSize)
for i in 0..<bufferSize {
    print(bufferedPointer[i])
}
```

Comment: `let bufferedPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: typedPointer, count: rawbufferSize)` `rawbufferSize` is in bytes but `count` is in type units.